# How to load data in partitioned table automatically

Tags: hive

I created an external but partitioned table as below

> CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE IF NOT EXISTS dividends ( ymd STRING, dividend
>   FLOAT ) PARTITIONED BY (exchange STRING, symbol STRING) ROW FORMAT
>   DELIMITED FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',';

I want to load data in such a way that for each unique partition value, it automatically forms a new partition and data goes in that .Is there any way?

Sample data below

```
NASDAQ,AMTD,2006-01-25,6.0
NASDAQ,AHGP,2009-11-09,0.44
NASDAQ,AHGP,2009-08-10,0.428
NASDAQ,AHGP,2009-05-11,0.415
NASDAQ,AHGP,2009-02-10,0.403
NASDAQ,AHGP,2008-11-07,0.39
NASDAQ,AHGP,2008-08-08,0.353
NASDAQ,AHGP,2008-05-09,0.288
NASDAQ,AHGP,2008-02-08,0.288
NASDAQ,AHGP,2007-11-07,0.265
NASDAQ,AHGP,2007-08-08,0.265
NASDAQ,AHGP,2007-05-09,0.25
NASDAQ,AHGP,2007-02-07,0.25
NASDAQ,AHGP,2006-11-07,0.215
NASDAQ,AHGP,2006-08-09,0.215
NASDAQ,ALEX,2009-11-03,0.315
NASDAQ,ALEX,2009-08-04,0.315
NASDAQ,ALEX,2009-05-12,0.315
NASDAQ,ALEX,2009-02-11,0.315
NASDAQ,ALEX,2008-11-04,0.315
NASDAQ,AFCE,2005-06-06,12.0
NASDAQ,ASRVP,2009-12-28,0.528
NASDAQ,ASRVP,2009-09-25,0.528
NASDAQ,ASRVP,2009-06-25,0.528
NASDAQ,ASRVP,2009-03-26,0.528
NASDAQ,ASRVP,2008-12-26,0.528
NASDAQ,ASRVP,2008-09-25,0.528
NASDAQ,ASRVP,2008-06-25,0.528
```

Comment: HIve has the dynamic partition concept for this , refer https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/DynamicPartitions

Answer (score 0):

I was searching for this. These were my steps, created a Staging table and loaded the csv file and then created and loaded the table using dynamic partition.

CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE  stocks ( `exchange`      STRING,
`symbol`          STRING,
`ymd`             STRING,
`price_open`      FLOAT,
`price_high`      FLOAT, 
`price_low`       FLOAT,
`price_close`     FLOAT,
`volume`          INT,
`price_adj_close` FLOAT) 
LOCATION '/user/hduser/stocks';

CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE IF NOT EXISTS dividends_stage (
`exchange`  STRING,
`symbol` STRING,
`ymd`  STRING,
`dividend`        FLOAT )
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' 
LOCATION '/user/hduser/div_stage';

hadoop fs -mv /user/hduser/dividends.csv /user/hduser/div_stage

CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE IF NOT EXISTS dividends (
`ymd`             STRING,
`dividend`        FLOAT )
PARTITIONED BY (`exchange` STRING, `symbol` STRING) 
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','  ;

INSERT OVERWRITE TABLE dividends partition (`exchange` , `symbol`)
SELECT `ymd`,`dividend`, `exchange`, `symbol` from  dividends_stage;

SELECT INPUT__FILE__NAME, BLOCK__OFFSET__INSIDE__FILE from dividends ;

Hope this helps and not too late..